# Add contacts to all new addresses

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-apps-script, google-apps-email

Is it possible to automatically add contacts to new GMail accounts created under your Google apps account? If so, how can I achieve such a thing?

Answer (score -2):

Did I got your question right, assuming, that you want to "extract" your Contacts into another GMail account?

If yes, just follow this "tutorial":
http://www.wikihow.com/Export-Gmail-Contacts

Sorry, if I got your question wrong. :)

Comment: Without the link, there is no useful information here.